# Laurent series in $z=-i \pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Let $f(z)= \frac{e^{az}}{1+e^{z}}$ and $0<a<1$.
Find Laurent series expansion centered at $z_0 = -i \pi$.

The biggest problem for me is to find this series centered at $z_0 $ which does not equal $0$. (I can do it in point $z_0 = 0$ and then principal part equal 0).

Comment: Write $z = z_0 + (z-z_0)$, let $w = z-z_0$. Use properties of the exponential function like $e^{u+v} = e^u\cdot e^v$ to simplify. You get an expression in $w$ that should look familiar. If it doesn't look familiar at all, look up "Bernoulli numbers".

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, so I have got something like this (I start with denominator):
$\frac{1}{1+e^{-i \pi}}e^{z+i \pi}$ = $\frac{1}{1+e^{-i \pi}(1+z+i \pi + \frac{(z+ i \pi )^2}{2!}+...}$ and then sum of geometric series. Is it correct? Then again principal part equal $0$ I guess./

Comment: No, there remains an $e^w$ term in the denominator.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, sorry problem with the Latex...
So I have $\frac{1}{1+e^{-i \pi}e^w}=\frac{1}{1- -e^{-i \pi}(1+w+\frac{w^2}{2!}+...)}$ and then should I transform it to sum of geometric series?

Comment: First, what is $e^{-i\pi}$? Writing that in a simpler way helps a lot. Then, do you only want the first few terms of the Laurent series, or the complete expansion? If you want the complete expansion, fiddling with geometric series won't cut it, then check out Bernoulli.